# Test if Object is a generic list of specific type

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

For various reasons, a method of mine accepts a generic `Object` argument. What the method does depends on the actual type, so I do some instanceof

Now, in one specific case, I need to check if the type is Iterable.

I have found that instanceof with generics does not work.

```
x instanceof Iterable<Integer>
```

So what are the alternatives, apart from looping through each element and testing their type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't influence the signature of your method or the Iterable instances you get, then there is no way to distinguish an instance of e.g. `Iterable<Object>` containing only integers from an instance of `Iterable<Integer>`. They are identical in every respect; in fact, the very concept "instance of `Iterable<Integer>`" is nebulous for this reason. Instances are runtime artifacts and constructor type parameters are a compile-time artifact.